# Automatically generate images from SWF

Tags: apache-flex, image, flash

I'm looking for something that automatically generates images from the content in some SWF and stores the images on a server to be fetched if the user doesn't have Flash Player installed. The purpose is to at least show a static diagram instead of just a table with data, if Flash Player isn't installed.

It's quite easy to create an image from a DisplayObject using Actionscript, but that requires someone opens the SWF in the first place. I would like this to execute on the server side. Is it possible? Is there a headless Flash Player that could be used with PHP for example?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a "shell" flash app that loaded in other swfs and took `bitmapData` "screenshots" at a predefined interval and dumped them to the server. You would have to be able to install the flash player server-side and run it from a command.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:
http://www.sephiroth.it/tutorials/flashPHP/print_screen/